# Error when following quickstart tutorial of angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2

I tried to follow this [angularfire2](https://github.com/IdanCo/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) quick start guide and run into errors described below. Should I skip this library and switch to [angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) anyway, because angularfire2 depends on CommonJS or AMD?

```
$ ng new firebase-test
$ cd firebase-test/
$ ng serve
```

Opened http://localhost:4200/ and checked if it works. Back to terminal interrupt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then:

```
$ npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
$ ng g environments
```

Then I modified `/src/environments/environment.ts` and `/src/app/app.module.ts` as described in the tutorial. The only difference was that I copied the content of environment.ts also to environment.development.ts.

app.module.ts:

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ]...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then  I start `ng serve` again and got lot of errors belonging to `app.component.html`. So I deleted content and end up with the following error:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   4.15 MB | 
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 333.16 kB | 
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 230.46 kB | 
main.js               | main          |   6.65 kB | 
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.52 kB | 

                      | Initial Total |   4.72 MB

Build at: 2023-07-15T21:06:50.060Z - Hash: d2bf63e1da851d4f - Time: 6116ms

Warning: ./firebase-test/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/es2015/firebase.app.module.js depends on 'firebase/app'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

./firebase-test/src/app/app.module.ts depends on 'angularfire2'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



Error: src/app/app.module.ts:14:12 - error NG1010: Value



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.
```

If I comment the following lines in app.modules.ts, then the app complies successfully.

```
//import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
...
//AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

Using Angular 16 and

```
├── angularfire2@5.4.2
├── firebase@7.24.0
```